# directly embedded subreport in JasperReports

Tags: syntax, jasper-reports, embedded-resource, subreport

I am so close to having this work, I am trying to directly embed one jasper subreport into the main report xml of the other.  You'd think this would be easy, but I can't find a single example on doing it.  Everyone seems to use files or resources or whatever.  I have one report working straight from a string and I want it to contain it's subreport.

Anyone?  Syntax?  Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand you correctly in that you want the main report and the sub-report to be defined in the same xml template file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of to do this with JasperReports is to use a separate .jrxml file for the subreport, and include it in the main report using the `subreport` command.

Another option you have for any embedded reports is to use subdatasets, but as far as I know they're only useful for graphs.

As it sounds like you control the code surrounding the generation of the report, you could come up with a simple format to define multiple reports in the one string, and then have your code extract each report at runtime.

When we've needed to deal with a single file but have subreports for a JasperReport, we've used Zip files, and simply zipped up the main report and all it's necessary sub reports, and then unzipped them into a temporary directory when we need to (all in code of course)

Comment: I have now indeed used the structure of my program to allow subreports as objects to be passed as parametsrs to another, and the dataSourceExpression of the subreport creates a "new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{SUBREPORT})"