# How to set up jasper reports in spring with subreports

Tags: spring, jasper-reports, subreports

I'm looking for a guide in  How to set up jasper reports in spring with subreports. I've got decent java and spring knowledge but jasper is confusing me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've tried following other people's questions and answers like 
[Subreports in Jasper Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067502/subreports-in-jasper-reports)
[directly embedded subreport in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929290/directly-embedded-subreport-in-jasper-report)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209977/jasper-report-updating-text-fields-in-a-subreport-with-the-page-numbers-of-subseq

but had no luck.

Just looking for a guide or something on it.

My main problem is that all the guides out there work with simple types. I need something that will explain to me how to work with complex types, like lists within lists. or collections etc.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I found that the reference didn't give me much advice using complex types which is my main problem. Sorry I didn't mention this in the question, but I have added it now. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the section"14.7.4. Working with Sub-Reports" [spring reference here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html#view-jasper-reports).

Are you looking for more than this info?